# Get response data when fail in downloadTaskWithRequest of AFURLSessionManager

Tags: afnetworking-3

I'm creating a download class which allow to download some file (music) from my server. For some time, the server return error (error code 500 or something) and the description of error will be in the data of the response.

The completionHandler only return NSURLResponse so it's just contain the header of response. How to get the body content in this case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request...

Comment: No, I think they want to implement by that way, they didn't through the reason of error to the error code inside the header, they return it in the body.